# Can you iterate through a 2nd database while iterating through the 1st database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I have 2 databases, the first with 10 entries (6 columns) and the second with 100 entries (3 columns). What I would like to do is after I iterate through a row of the first database I iterate through each row of the second database.

I'd like to print something like

`echo $db1->col1, $db2->col1, $db2->col4`

But unsure how to iterate through the second db while iterating through the first.

Comment: Do you really mean 2 databases? Or 2 tables?

Comment: It's possible a `JOIN` operation is what you want. Can't tell from your question. But JOIN is a common way of combining data from two tables. I agree with Mark Baker—you probably mean *tables* when you say *databases*. Think of a database like a folder, and tables as files in the folder.

Comment: You mean for every loop of your first database table $db1 you want to loop through all the rows of $db2 rows. Right?

Comment: show your schema (DB table structure). That will give us a better idea of what you're working with. Essentially you want to have a foreign key on your table to use JOINs as mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks everyone. The foreach solution below solved the problem. Really appreciate the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

Think that you have your first database as $db1_results and second database results as $db2_results.

What you need is, for every loop of first database you need to loop through all the rows of the second database.

Which can be achieved as follows :

```
foreach($db1_results as $db1_result){
    /* Eg: db1 has 10 records and db2 has 1000 records. 
For every 1 iternation of $db1, you will loop 1000 records of your $db2 */
    foreach($db2_results as $db2_result){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are on the same database server you can do the following:

**SQL Solution**

```
SELECT * FROM table1,table2
```

This will give you a new table where each row from table1 is joined with each row of table2

I think you can do this with other database languages too.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join

Comment: Thanks. The foreach solution above solved my problem.